# Is there a way to configure MDBs programatically?

Tags: glassfish, ejb, jms, ejb-3.1

I am currently working on a EJB 3.1 based project running on GlassFish that uses a custom built framework to configure the functionality of any SessionBeans. Using this we can enable, disable and re-configure most of the services at run-time. Unfortunately we can't extend this to support conifguration of MDBs. I would like to set the selector a MDB is using based upon the configuration information and re-configure this if the settings change.

Unfortunately I could only come up with a SessionBean that creates MessageConsumers natively on the JMS Sessions based upon the configuration and to have the JMS messages handleb by MessageListeners, but I was told this way we would be loosing concurrency and the transaction handling of the EJB system, as we would no longer be using MDBs this way.

So is there any way to do what I'm looking for using MDBs? Someone told me there are some planned extensions in new EJB and JMS spec drafts, but I couln't find a pointer to that particular topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, MDBs are configured by the Deployer at deploy-time.

Similar question answered here: [Configuring MappedName annotation in Message Driven Bean dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16033568/configuring-mappedname-annotation-in-message-driven-bean-dynamically/26294397#26294397)